# Why doesn't margin-right work if the child div bigger than it's parent?

Tags: html, css

Suppose I have two divs - the parent and the child. The parent div has width 200px and the child has 105% width. Now the right edge of child will flow outwards. Here is the code:

```css
.container1 {
              width: 200px; height: 200px;
              border: 1px solid black;
              margin-left: 100px;
}
.container2{
              width: 105%;
              border: 1px dotted red;
              height: 200px;
              margin-right: 10%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container1">
  <div class="container2"></div> 
</div>
```

My question why doesn't the margin-right, having either positive or negative value, work on the child div? On the other hand margin-left work with both positive and negative values.

Comment: Off topic: I'd advise you avoid using pixels as a unit. It's better to use percentages/em/rem as it will allow for responsive styling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`margin-right` is working, but .container2 is bigger than its parent and you don't see the effect. Remember browsers render from left to right, from top to down.

If you want to have a visible right margin, no matter the .container2 width, you need to set `float: right;`

```
.container2 { 
    width: 105%;
    border: 1px dotted red;
    height: 200px;
    margin-right: 10%;
    position: relative;
    float: right; 
}
```

Comment: Means,  due to the child being bigger than it's parent there is nothing to right of child div. So it is is not pushing against the parent's right border.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a positive or negative margin value. In your code you got a typo. 
It should be :

```
margin-right: 10%;
```

**Update**

If you want to see the margin allocated when doing an inspect element you can use `display: inline-block` to the child element. But since you set a width to it's parent it would still not have any effect or will not push the element next to it.

```css
.container1 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-left: 100px;
}
.container2 {
  width: 105%;
  border: 1px dotted red;
  height: 200px;
  margin-right: 10%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container1">
  <div class="container2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nah, it still doesn't work after correcting the typo.

Comment: @user31782 updated my answer.